# Wrap Column name while generating PDF from UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

I have 7 columns UITableView in my iPad application.

I am succeeded to generate PDF from this but last column name is not showing correctly as 
it has more characters than column width. (column name is showing out of table boundaris)

I am also not able to wrap this column name.

What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: can you show some code of it? or if you have the solution already - post it please as the answer